# Rewrite a method in Rust to use `&mut self` instead of `mut self`

Tags: rust

I'm writing a Minesweeper implementation in Rust. For the time being, it consists of the `enum Cell` which represents a cell of the field

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Cell {
    Mine,
    Flag,
    Empty(u8),
}
```

And the `struct Feild` which represents the field itself

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Field(Vec<Vec<Cell>>);
```

So, baiscally, the field is just a tuple holding one element: a vector of vectors containing cells.

There's currently a single implementation for the `Field` struct:

```rust
impl Field {
    pub fn new(width: u8, height: u8, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<Self, ()> { ... }

    pub fn get_size(&self) -> (u8, u8, u16) { ... }

    fn insert_mines(mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<Self, ()> { ... }
}
```

The `new` associated function, as by convenstions, allows to create an instance of `Field`. The `get_size` method returns the dimensions of the field. The private `insert_mines` method randomly adds the specified amount of mines to the field.

The `main()` function looks like this

```rust
fn main() {
    let field = field::Field::new(9, 9, 9).unwrap();

    println!("{}", field)
}
```

I'm creating a 9 by 9 field with 9 mines in it and then print the field (`Display` traits are properly implemented for both `Field` and `Cell`, but I won't show it here since it's not of our interest).

When creating an instance, the `new` associated function is invoked:

```rust
pub fn new(width: u8, height: u8, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        let mut field = Field(vec![vec![Cell::Empty(0); width as usize]; height as usize]);

        field = field.insert_mines(number_of_mines)?;

        Ok(field)
    }
```

it subsequently calls the `insert_mines` method. Here it goes

```rust
fn insert_mines(mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        // get the width of a single row and the total cells number of the field
        let (width, _, total_number_of_cells) = self.get_size();

        // return an error if the required number of mines is less than 1 or is more than the total number of cells
        // minus 1 (there should always be at least one cell without a mine)
        if number_of_mines < 1 || number_of_mines > (total_number_of_cells - 1) {
            return Err(());
        }

        // flatten the field for an easier interaction with it
        let mut flattened_field = self.0.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<Cell>>();

        flattened_field.splice(
            0..number_of_mines as usize,
            (0..number_of_mines)
                .map(|_| Cell::Mine)
                .collect::<Vec<Cell>>(),
        );

        // shuffle the flattened field to randomly distribute the mines
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        flattened_field.shuffle(&mut rng);

        // convert the flattened fields back into its original `Vec<Vec<u16>>` form
        self.0 = flattened_field
            .chunks(width as usize)
            .map(|chunk| chunk.to_vec())
            .collect::<Vec<Vec<Cell>>>();

        Ok(self)
    }
```

It works the following way:

1. Flattening the `Vec<Vec<Cell>>` into `Vec<Cell>` (so that it's easier to work with)
2. Replacing the first `n` elements with `Cell::Mine`
3. Shuffling the vector
4. Reconstructing the `Vec<Vec<Cell>>` from `Vec<Cell>` and setting the result as `self.0` (therefore updating the original field with the new one)

Everything works correctly. When the program is run, it prints something like

```
□ □ □ * □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ * □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ * □ □ * □ 
* □ □ * □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ * □ □ □ * 
□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ 
□ * □ □ □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □
```

which is totally correct (squares are empty cells and `*` are mines).

**However**, I don't like the way the `insert_mines` method takes ownership of the field. In fact, I'm not even sure whether it's bad or not. If it's OK, then I'd like to know why it's OK in that particular case (while generally it's recommended to give parameters as less "access power" as possible). If it's not good indeed and should better be rewritten to use e.g. `&mut self`, then I'd like to know how to do so, because with my own attempts I experience issues.

---

Regarding **my attempts**:

I'm starting with updating the signature of the insert_mines method

`fn insert_mines(mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<Self, ()> { ... }` becomes `fn insert_mines(&mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<(), ()> { ... }`.

Then in the `new` a.f. appears the following error:

```rust
field = field.insert_mines(number_of_mines)?;

// Type mismatch [E0308] expected `Field`, but found `()` 
`?` operator has incompatible types [E0308] expected `Field`, found `()` Note: `?` operator cannot convert from `()` to `field::Field`
```

Expected. The method should update the field in-place, so no need to assign anything anymore. Removing the `field =`  part.

Then there appears an error in the `insert_mines` itself:

```rust
// flatten the field for an easier interaction with it
let mut flattened_field = self.0.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<Cell>>();

// cannot move out of `self` which is behind a mutable reference [E0507] move occurs because `self.0` has type `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<field::cell::Cell>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait Note: `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `self.0` Help: you can `clone` the value and consume it, but this might not be your desired behavior
```

Keep fixing the issues, and here's what it comes down to:

```rust
fn insert_mines(&mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<(), ()> {
        // get the width of a single row and the total cells number of the field
        let (width, _, total_number_of_cells) = self.get_size();

        // return an error if the required number of mines is less than 1 or is more than the total number of cells
        // minus 1 (there should always be at least one cell without a mine)
        if number_of_mines < 1 || number_of_mines > (total_number_of_cells - 1) {
            return Err(());
        }

        // flatten the field for an easier interaction with it
        let mut flattened_field = self.0.iter_mut().flatten().collect::<Vec<&mut Cell>>();

        flattened_field.splice(
            0..number_of_mines as usize,
            (0..number_of_mines)
                .into_iter()
                .map(|_| &mut Cell::Mine)
                .collect::<Vec<&mut Cell>>(),
        );

        // shuffle the flattened field to randomly distribute the mines
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        flattened_field.shuffle(&mut rng);

        // convert the flattened fields back into its original `Vec<Vec<u16>>` form
        self.0 = flattened_field
            .chunks(width as usize)
            .map(|chunk| chunk.to_vec())
            .collect::<Vec<Vec<&mut Cell>>>();

        Ok(())
    }
```

The error is now on the line with `self.0 = ...` and says

```
mismatched types [E0308] expected `Vec<Vec<Cell>>`, found `Vec<Vec<&mut Cell>>` Note: expected struct `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<field::cell::Cell>>` found struct `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<&mut field::cell::Cell>>`
Type mismatch [E0308] expected `Vec<Vec<Cell>>`, but found `Vec<Vec<&mut Cell>>`
```

As I can understand, it means that the `Field(Vec<Vec<Cell>>)` expects a vector of `Cell`s, but what I'm trying to assign it is a vecor of mutable references to `Cell`s.

So, I'm thinking that maybe I'm taking an incorrect approach. Or maybe the approach is correct, but there's something I'm missing with the implementation (my idea is to convert `<Vec<Vec<&mut Cell>>` back into `<Vec<Vec<Cell>>` somehow, but no idea exactly *how*). Generally, I'm looking for guidance regarding my problem and a feedback about my current approach.

Comment: If you want to do things in place, you should use an algorithm that works in place, not one deconstructs the vectors, creates a temporary and then does the reverse. Your current one is likely not going to benefit at all from mutating.

Comment: You can use `.drain(..)` instead of `.into_iter()`

Comment: @cafce25 please, elaborate. > an algorithm that works in place - which one? > Your current one is likely not going to benefit at all from mutating - why? > You can use .drain(..) instead of .into_iter() - how's it different and why it's better?

Comment: `.drain(..)` is better simply because it works with a `&mut self` as receiver instead of just not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution can actually be closer to the version that takes ownership than you think. Rust has a built-in function called [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) that allows you to take ownership of mutably borrowed values.

Here's where you can use it in your code.

```rust
fn insert_mines(&mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<(), ()> {
    let mut temp_self = Field(Vec::new());
    std::mem::swap(self, &mut temp_self);
```

Before anything, you swap the borrowed `self` with an owned `temp_self`. For the rest of the function, `self` will contain an empty grid, and you'll use `temp_self` instead of `self`. For example:

```rust
    // flatten the field for an easier interaction with it
    let mut flattened_field = temp_self.0.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<Cell>>();
```

And finally, at the end you can use `swap` again to return the real field to `self`.

```rust
    std::mem::swap(self, &mut temp_self);
    Ok(())
}
```

---

Getting more specific, since `Vec` implements `Default`, you can use [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) to obtain the value in less code. This swaps out just the data inside of `Field`, so you call it on `self.0` instead of `self`. At the top of the function:

```rust
let temp_self = Field(std::mem::take(&mut self.0));
```

And separately, since you don't actually need the placeholder `Vec` that's sitting in `self`, you can just overwrite it with assignment.

```rust
*self = temp_self;
Ok(())
```

---

All the previous ideas work generally for types that can be quickly constructed (which is most types), but for your specific case, you don't actually need ownership to do any of the things you're doing. There's numerous ways to do this, but one way is to collect all your `Cell` references, shuffle them, and then set the first ones to mines.

```rust
fn insert_mines(&mut self, number_of_mines: u16) -> Result<(), ()> {
    // get the width of a single row and the total cells number of the field
    let (_, _, total_number_of_cells) = self.get_size();

    // return an error if the required number of mines is less than 1 or is more than the total number of cells
    // minus 1 (there should always be at least one cell without a mine)
    if number_of_mines < 1 || number_of_mines > (total_number_of_cells - 1) {
        return Err(());
    }

    // flatten the field for an easier interaction with it
    let mut flattened_field = self.0.iter_mut().flatten().collect::<Vec<&mut Cell>>();

    // shuffle the flattened field to randomly distribute the mines
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    flattened_field.shuffle(&mut rng);

    for cell in flattened_field.into_iter().take(number_of_mines as usize) {
        *cell = Cell::Mine;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

---

There's far more you can do to make this more idiomatic and perform better, but that is for another post.

Comment: So, generally speaking, the idea of taking ownership of the `field` is not good? I should try to use the mutable borrow instead, right?

And the last code snipped of yours shows exactly that? But why you first shuffle the flattened array and only after that change first `number_of_mines` cells to Mines?

Comment: Just tested your solution, and it actually works. Though I don't understand why. If we flatten the vector of empty cells and then take `n` first cells to insert mines into, why the mines then are distributed randomly?

Comment: @smellyshovel 1) it's not bad to take ownership of the field, it's just unnecessary, since better solutions exist that don't need to do that. 2) `flattened_field` holds references to the original field. These are in the same order, so the first `&mut Cell` points to the first `Cell` in the first row. Then, they are shuffled, so the first `&mut Cell` points to a random `Cell`. Then, the first `n` `&mut Cell`s are set to `Mine`s, which sets `n` random `Cell`s to `Mine`s.